# Delay text selection mode after touch

Tags: settings, touchscreen, accessibility, text-selection

When a text is displayed e.g. in Chrome, you can switch to text selection mode with a long-press.

I often enter this mode accidentally when I only want to scroll slowly. I tend to scroll continuously while reading long texts.

Is there a setting to prevent this? Can I increase the delay before a long-press causes text selection mode, or increase the threshold so that even a very slow scrolling motion is detected as scrolling?

Can I somehow disable text selection entirely for specific apps?

I tried changing "accessibility / timing controls / touch and hold delay" but that did not appear to change anything. It is currently back to "short"

The problem occurs in various applications that allow scrolling as well as selecting text: Chrome, Firefox, Lithium.

Pixel 6 pro, Android 13